# Error 3080004: Transaction exceeded the current CPU usage limit imposed on the transaction

Tags: cleos, staking, stake

I have an account with very little staked CPU/NET but I need to do some transfers of another token and I currently can't do anything:

```
$ cleos -u https://api.eosnewyork.io:443 get account auewijsdh312
[...]
net bandwidth: 
     staked:          0.1000 EOS
[...]
cpu bandwidth:
     staked:          0.1000 EOS
     delegated:       0.0000 EOS
     used:             2.463 ms   
     available:            0 us   
     limit:                9 us   

EOS balances: 
     liquid:            0.0003 EOS
     staked:            0.2000 EOS
     unstaking:         0.0000 EOS
     total:             0.2003 EOS [...]
```

Even forgetting how little liquid EOS the account has, it doesn't have enough CPU to stake any more EOS, so even if I could transfer EOS to it, I don't think it will help:

```
$ cleos --url http://api.eosnewyork.io system delegatebw auewijsdh312 auewijsdh312 "0.0001 EOS" "0.0001 EOS"
Error 3080004: Transaction exceeded the current CPU usage limit imposed on the transaction
Error Details:
billed CPU time (1450 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (9 us)
```

So then I created a new account in Scatter thinking that I would be able to then stake some CPU/NET in that account and then delegatebw the stake over to the above account. I wasn't sure if this would all work, so I started by just creating an account with 2 EOS:

```
$ cleos -u https://api.eosnewyork.io:443 get account jlkjdfalkjiw
[...]
net bandwidth: 
     staked:          0.0512 EOS
[...]
cpu bandwidth:
     staked:          0.1536 EOS
     delegated:       0.0000 EOS
     used:                 0 us   
     available:           14 us   
     limit:               14 us   

EOS balances: 
     liquid:            1.5134 EOS
     staked:            0.2048 EOS
     unstaking:         0.0000 EOS
     total:             1.7182 EOS [...]
```

But again, I can't even stake any more CPU/NET with this new account:

```
$ cleos --url http://api.eosnewyork.io system delegatebw jlkjdfalkjiw jlkjdfalkjiw "0.0001 EOS" "0.0001 EOS"
Error 3080004: Transaction exceeded the current CPU usage limit imposed on the transaction
Error Details:
billed CPU time (1943 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (14 us)
```

So does this mean that Scatter is creating accounts with insufficient CPU/NET staked? Or perhaps it just stakes a proportion of how much is transferred on creation? If so, how much should I be creating it with to have enough to do something with the account?

Alternatively, should I just create an account using cleos with `cleos --url http://api.eosnewyork.io system newaccount --stake-net TEXT --stake-cpu TEXT`? If so, how much should I stake to start?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say how much you should stake when setting up a new contract, the amount of CPU you get fluctuates with supply and demand and so any answer given here will be out of date in the future.

There are websites such as bloks.io that allow you 5 free transactions per day, you could use one of these websites to stake more EOS to yourself. If you don't have enough EOS you could lease EOS using the REX (also available on bloks.io) or another service such as Chintai.